# Is it possible to have TriggeredSendDefinition send emails only once a day?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I would like to make a `TriggeredSendDefintion` which once a day [say at 9am] grabs everyone in its `SendSourceDataExtension`, and send them an email. Is this possible with a `TriggeredSendDefinition`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, not with a TriggeredSendDefinition.  Triggers only fire via API call and you have to send the audience with the call.

A [User-Initiated Send](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/) is what you're looking for.  It's a combination of an audience (List, Data Extension or Filter) and an email.

You can automate the send of a User-Initiated Send Definition on some interval using a [Program](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/programs/) or Automation in [Automation Studio](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/automation_studio/using_the_automation_studio_overview_page/).